# Handler memory leaks

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I have spent like 15 hours trying to fixed my memory problem then read some questions about that but, I don't really find a good answer and solution.

I am sending two integers every time the MediaPlayer time is updated from [setOnBufferingUpdateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnBufferingUpdateListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener)) using a Handler. then set the integers to two TextViews. But each time the time updates. the Android studio's Android monitor show me the memory incrementing by one megabyte.

I don't want that. Here my classes.

The handler:

```
public class UpdateH extends android.os.Handler {

private OnUpdate onUpdate;

public UpdateH() {
}

public UpdateH(Callback callback) {
    super(callback);
}

public UpdateH(Looper looper) {
    super(looper);
}

public UpdateH(Looper looper, Callback callback) {
    super(looper, callback);
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    onUpdate.update(msg.arg1, msg.arg2);
}

public void setOnUpdate(OnUpdate onUpdate) {
    this.onUpdate = onUpdate;
}

public interface OnUpdate{
    void update(int cu, int t);
}
```

}

in the fragment:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Player.playerProgressHandler = null;
    mu = null;
}

private UpdateH mu;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mu = new UpdateH(Looper.getMainLooper());

    mu.setOnUpdate(new UpdateH.OnUpdate() {
        @Override
        public void update(int cu, int t) {
            setTime(cu, t);
        }
    });
    Player.playerProgressHandler = mu;
}

private void setTime(int current, int total){
    this.current.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
            (int) ((current / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
            (int) ((current / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
            (int) (current / 1000) % 60));

    this.total.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",
            (int) ((total / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
            (int) ((total / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
            (int) (total / 1000) % 60));
}
```

In the thread:

```
if(playerProgressHandler != null && mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){
                    Message message = Message.obtain();
                    message.setTarget(playerProgressHandler);
                    message.arg1 = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    message.arg2 = mp.getDuration();
                    message.sendToTarget();
                }
```

The problem comes from the setTime method. Because when I comment the codes in it. The memory stays cool.

**Note: AsyncTask cannot fix it, if think about AsyncTask**

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a Thread, you need to cancel it in your onDestroy (or possibly onPause or onStop, if it doesn't need to be running when you're off screen) so it exits and can be garbage collected.  Once the thread is garbage collected, there will be no references left to the text views, which will allow the rest of the activity to be garbage collected.  Make sure the Runnable exits-  this means it needs to check if the Thread has been canceled in its main loop.

If you're posting to handlers in a self-referential loop, you need to remove all messages from the Handler in the same spot.

And just an FYI-  your whole updater is far more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Like I said, the problem is not about the thread. The integers are sent by the MediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener callback. It's about the settext method to the TextView.

Comment: You're wrong-  it is about the Thread.  The thread continues after the Activity is destroyed, but it has a reference to the Activity due to the call to set the textview.  That causes the entire Activity and all associated views and variables to leak.  Fix the thread and the leak goes.

Comment: But I cannot fix the thread because I am using the [MediaPlayer class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). My codes are called when the MediaPlayer time is updated from the setOnBufferingUpdateListener. **I did not create a thread to update my TextView. That thread is from android and I cannot do nothing about. Plus, The code works fine, becuase when I close the activity, the memory does not increment because I set the handler to null when activity onPause**

Comment: I think you're just very confused about what's happening on what threads when.  Your question combined with your updates make no sense.  And the media player doesn't make callbacks off the UI thread.  But I can assure you setText does not cause a memory leak.

Comment: Your maybe right about the setText to the Textview. But the problem comes from the setTime called from my handler from setOnBufferingUpdateListener. becuase, when I comment all code in the setTime method or when I pause the mediaPlayer, The memory stays cool. The problem comes from my setTime called by setOnBufferingUpdateListener. Or maybe my Handler. I 'm gonna fine another way to update my Textview without using the handler to see what happend

Comment: I'ts ok now. I wait for some minutes. then the Memory decrease alone. It's that it's only slow to clear the non reference variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'ts ok now. I wait for some minutes. then the Memory decrease alone. It's that, it's only slow to clear the non referenced variables.